# Execute a bean's method before it may be used in the JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

A request scoped bean collects data, from all many other request beans & business logic. This bean is used through the EL expressions in the page but before this request scoped bean may be used in the page, it needs to build a directory using the collected data (This is done after all collection is over but before the bean properties may be used in page).

How can I execute the building of the directory in this bean after all collection but before it is used through the EL expressions in the page without using `<f:event>`? I need to build it only once.

```
@ManagedBean(name="namesDirectory")
@RequestScoped
public class NamesDirectory { 

    public void addForPersonNameRetrieval(Integer id) { // this is used to collect the data in bean
           peopleNamesMap.put(id,null);
           .......
    }

    public void buildDirectory(){ // used, when all collection is over, to build the diirectory      
           .......
    }

    public String getPersonName(Integer id) { // used in the JSF page through EL expressions
        name = peopleNamesMap.get(id);
    }

}
```

Here `buildDirectory()` needs to be executed at the end of all collection but before using `getPersonName()` in the JSF page

Comment: Isn't there any more beautiful solution than what @Udo Held suggested for building it only once ?

Comment: The pattern below only causes one rebuild.

Comment: Yes Udo, I got that :) & +1 -ed  your answer for that! However I was wondering  if there were solutions perhaps through some kind of event listeners, i dont know about phase listeners but thinking from their name I was wondering if they were meant for somewhat this kind of purpose.. otherwise your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got several options. You could rebuild the directory after every insert or before every retrieval, however this may cause unnecessary rebuilds. You could rebuild the directory only when needed and called:

- Add a flag `requiresRebuild` and default it to `true`.
- Set it to `true` in `addForPersonaNameRetrieval`.
- Set it to `false` in `buildDirectory`.
- Call `buildDirectory` in `getPersonName` if a rebuild is necessary.